# LibGDX - Shader not being applied

Tags: java, libgdx

I've recently encountered a strange problem with my program and I can't seem to fix it. When I try to apply a shader to my `SpriteBatch` it doesn't change. I've debugged this problem like so:

```
if (test) {
    System.out.println("Batch shader: " + stage.getBatch().getShader());
    System.out.println("Default shader: " + Assets.getDefaultShader());
    System.out.println("Default batch: " + Assets.SPRITE_BATCH);
    System.out.println("Stage batch: " + stage.getBatch());
}

stage.getBatch().setShader(null);
if (test)
    System.out.println("Batch shader: " + stage.getBatch().getShader()); //Should print null
stage.act();
if (test)
    System.out.println("Batch shader: " + stage.getBatch().getShader());
stage.draw();
if (test)
    System.out.println("Batch shader: " + stage.getBatch().getShader());
test = false;
```

All of those shaders print the exact same thing, and the batches are also the same (the batches are supposed to be the same). Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sitting with this problem for hours I finally found out what was wrong.

If you set the shader to `null` on your `SpriteBatch`, it uses the default shader provided to the `SpriteBatch`. For me, the default shader was `Assets.getDefaultShader()`, so when I set the shader to null it just used that shader. I fixed this by simply not settings a default shader to the `SpriteBatch`.